# Is it possible to use non-alphabetical sorting of using statements in Rider?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

I'm using JetBrains Rider for C# in Unity.

When I add a missing `using` statement, Rider sorts all namespaces alphabetically. However, I'd like a different sorting order.

I want `using` statements for my own packages to be placed after those for standard packages like `System`, `Unity`, etc.

Is there a way to configure Rider to do this?

I found an option in Rider / Settings that force System* and Windows* to be at the beginning. But it doesn't place Unity packages at the beggining as well.

Comment: no, that's not possible

Comment: This is indeed not possible, but you can file a feature request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP